# Format USB drive

Tags: partition, usb, disk-usage, mkfs

I have a USB drive which I format with

```
sudo mkfs.vfat -I /dev/sdb1
```

When I then look at the size of the USB drive with `df -h`, it reports its size to be 64 MB, though it should be 8 GB. What am I doing wrong?

`fdisk -l /dev/sdb1` gives

```
Disk /dev/sdb1: 67 MB, 67108864 bytes
241 heads, 62 sectors/track, 8 cylinders, total 131072 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
```

Comment: It looks like this USB drive has several partitions. What's the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sdb`?

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Not `fdisk -l /dev/sdb1` (which lists the partitions inside the partition `sdb1`). Run `fdisk -l /dev/sdb`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be `mkfs.vfat -I /dev/sdb`. `sdb1` indicates you probably have more than one partition, and you're just formatting the first one, which happens to be 64MiB.